# Problem saving WebView scroll position during orientation change in Android 2.1

Tags: android, webview, scroll-position

I have a problem preserving the current scroll position of content loaded in Android's WebView control during orientation changes. The issue currently exist only in Android 2.1 and Android 2.1 Update 1

The code that I use is based on the default Browser application and looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mWebView = new WebView(this);
  setContentView(mWebView);
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

  if (savedInstanceState != null)
  {
    final WebBackForwardList list = mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    if (list == null)
      return;

    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("currentPicture"))
    {
       final File f = new File(savedInstanceState.getString("currentPicture"));
       mWebView.restorePicture(savedInstanceState, f);
       f.delete();
    }
  }else
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
 }

 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
 {
   final WebBackForwardList list = mWebView.saveState(outState);
   File mThumbnailDir = getDir("thumbnails", 0);
   if (list != null)
   {
     final File f = new File(mThumbnailDir, mWebView.hashCode() + "_pic.save");
     if (mWebView.savePicture(outState, f))
        outState.putString("currentPicture", f.getPath());
   }
 }
```

This code works in Android 1.5, 1.6 and 2.0.1.  In Android 2.1 the same code restores the position for a split second but then the page reloads and scrolls to position 0,0.

In Android 2.1 Update 1, it not only scrolls back to 0,0, but also changes the Zoom to fit the page width (similar to the browser Overview mode introduced in 2.1)

Does anyone know of a workaround or has any idea what may cause such behavior?

Comment: Did you try comparing the source of WebView between the two versions, see what changed?  Might give a clue as to whats going on..

Comment: I did try comparing sources. The are quite bit of changes between 1.6 and 2.0 (including the addition of Overview Mode). Unless you really know the internals of how WebView works it is very difficult to figure out what exactly caused that change in behavior. What makes it even more frustrating is that I can't even debug thru the source I have because I don't have the exact version of the source that matches what the emulator or the device it running.

Comment: This can be worked around for orientation changes, but not for the user leaving the Activity and coming back later. It seems, the position is not properly stored in the Bundle - or the value is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Just load the WebViewState in onRestoreInstanceState.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the orientation from landscape to portrait or vise-versa, it starts the new activity. Hence you the open as refreshed activity.
Put the the code in your AndroidManifest.xml and reload app.

```
 "activity android:name=".Main
 android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in activity tab. Thanks